# How to force angular temporarily unwatch variable?

Tags: angularjs

I have articles json. When some event happens, I need to make multiple slicing of it. Now every single slice force update html, which is undesired for me. I would like Angular to stop watching my variable, then I do my "fancy" changes, and tell Angular to start watching articles json again. Is this possible?

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2QR4s/3/

I have already found such method, but it unbinds watch forever and I could not find how to rebind again:

```
var myevent = $scope.$on('someEvents', handleSomeEvent);
myevent() ; // unbinds the event
```

Comment: You just have to broadcast or emit the event whenever you want to trigger your callback.

Comment: Why don't you do your fancy changes before you slice it out of the array.  Maybe by setting some condition on the object? Then actually remove the object from the array when you don't want it to show up in the html

Comment: I don't understand Mik378 advice, jsfiddle would be helpful. JoseM: I already tried to clone my articles json without a reference, do my fancy changes and assign back to the original articles json. But my object is a bit more complicated than just simple list of articles and copying/reassigning it raises other issues I could not solve. So I thought it would be much easier to ask Angular stop watching for a while.

Comment: Why not create a copy of the data, perform your magic, and assign the result back when you done? See http://jsfiddle.net/jDLC4/1/